# How do browsers treat 'Authorization: Bearer'?

Tags: http-headers

Will this header persist for future requests for the duration of the browser session? Just the tab/window? Do I need to do something special in order to cause this?

Answer (score 0):

I am in the process of working out Athorization for a web app and as I currently understand it bearer tokens need to be sent with each request.